# Postgres index with sha() function in expression

Tags: postgresql, hash, database-indexes

The [`sha` functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-binarystring.html) in postgres only take `bytea` as input type.

```
sha512 ( bytea ) → bytea
    Computes the SHA-512 hash of the binary string.
    sha512('abc'::bytea) → \xddaf35a193617abacc417349ae204131​12e6fa4e89a97ea20a9eeee64b55d39a​2192992a274fc1a836ba3c23a3feebbd​454d4423643ce80e2a9ac94fa54ca49f
```

The problem is that casting like shown in the documentation (`'abc'::bytea`) does **not work** if the input text contains a backslash (Error: `invalid input syntax for type bytea`). And the only way i could find to convert such a string to `bytea` is this function:

```
convert_to ( string text, dest_encoding name ) → bytea
  Converts a text string (in the database encoding) to a binary string encoded in encoding dest_encoding (see Section 23.3.4 for available conversions).
  convert_to('some_text', 'UTF8') → \x736f6d655f74657874
```

**But** this function is not immutable thus it can't be used in a `UNIQUE INDEX` like this one:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name ON public.table
  USING btree
  (
    (md5(message)), -- works
    (sha512(convert_to(message, 'UTF8'))) -- not immutable
  );
```

**Question:** How to use the `sha` functions in a index expression? I don't want to use `md5`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double the backslash:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name ON public.table
  USING btree
  (
    (sha512(replace(message, '\', '\\')::bytea))
  );
```

Comment: I'm wondering if this will work in any case - aren't there other _identifiers_ which result in similar errors when casting to `bytea`? It looks really ugly.

Comment: Yes, that is safe - read `byteain` in `src/backend/utils/adt/varlena.c`. Sorry if it doesn't appeal to your sense of esthetics.

Comment: Found `varlena.c` source [here](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/def5b065ff22a16a80084587613599fe15627213/src/backend/utils/adt/varlena.c#L305). I expected the usage example `sha512('abc'::bytea) → ...` to work properly for all types of input string or at least a note on the page would be good. There is also another function `digest('\bla', 'sha512')` of the [pgcrypto](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgcrypto.html) module which handles the escaping.